# ng-dynamic-forms material not showing async validation error-message until focus on element

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using ng-dynamic-forms library with material components library.
I have a input field with a async validator. which works. But when I enter a incorrect value.
The validator is fired and returns an error, but the errormessage is only displayed if i select the field again.

I want it displayed as soon as the validator returns the error.

Now my form is INVALID but i don't see errors on the screen.

Comment: Can you please provide part of your code ?

Comment: same issue here. got a solution?